When using terraform to deploy codepipeline I get a deployment error
Below are my codebuild and codepipeline resource blocks
resource "aws_codebuild_project" "xxxx_build" {
name = "xxxx-project"
service_role = aws_iam_role.iam_for_codebuild.arn

source {
  type = "GITHUB"
  location = "https://github.com/oihuegbu/terraformproject.git"
}

environment {
    compute_type = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
    image = "aws/codebuild/amazonlinux-x86_64-standard:5.0"
    type = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
}

artifacts {
  type = "NO_ARTIFACTS"
}
}

resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline" {
name     = "xxxx-pipeline"
role_arn = aws_iam_role.iam_for_codepipeline.arn

artifact_store {
    location = aws_s3_bucket.codepipeline_bucket.bucket
    type = "S3"
}

stage {
  name = "Source"
  action {
    name = "GitHubSource"
    category = "Source"
    owner = "ThirdParty"
    provider = "Github"
    output_artifacts = ["SourceOutput"]
    version = "1"

    configuration = {
        Owner = "oihuegbu"
        Repo = "terraformproject"
        Branch = "main"
        OAuthToken = var.github_token
    }
  }
}

stage {
  name = "Build"
  action {
    name = "Build"
    category = "Build"
    owner = "AWS"
    provider = "CodeBuild"
    input_artifacts = ["SourceOutput"]
    output_artifacts = ["build_output"]
    version = "1"

    configuration = {
        ProjectName = "xxxx"
    }
  }      
}
}

However I get this error when tryinig to deploy
    │ Error: Error creating CodePipeline: InvalidActionDeclarationException: ActionType 
(Category: 'Source', Provider: 'Github', Owner: 'ThirdParty', Version: '1') in action 
'GitHubSource' is not available in region 'US_EAST_1'
    │ 
    │   with aws_codepipeline.codepipeline,
    │   on codepipeline.tf line 1, in resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline":
    │    1: resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline" {


I think it's just a typo in your provider setting. Try changing this:
provider = "Github"

To this:
provider = "GitHub"


That worked. It was a syntax issue. Thank you!
